# Scheme: confusion with set!

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm confused how this code works:

```
(define m (list 1 2 3 '(5 8)))
(let ((l (cdr m)))
(set! l '(28 88))) ==>(1 2 3 (5 8))

(define o (list 1 2 3 '(5 8)))
(let ((l (cdr o)))
(set-car! l '(28 88))) ==> (1 (28 88) 3 (5 8))
```

Why does `(set! l '(28 88)))` not update `m`?

Answer (score 7):

set! can't mutate a list (or any other structure, unlike set-car/cdr!), but only change the binding of a (in your case, the local *l*) variable.

```
(define x 3)
(define f (lambda (x) (set! x 4)))
(define g (lambda (y) (set! x y)))
(f x)
x 
-> 3
(g 5)
x
-> 5
```

Answer (score 1):

As per skeptic's answer, l was a locally-bound variable, and changing it via set! is not going to do anything to m.

If you want the first let to return the expected value, you need to follow-up by returning the new value of the locally-bound l, like so:

```
(define m (list 1 2 3 '(5 8)))
(let ((l (cdr m)))
(set! l '(28 88))
  l)

(28 88)
```

Answer (score 1):

`set!` only changes the binding of a symbol, often letting the garbage collector consume its original value. It doesn't mutate data, it rebinds a symbol. Hence things like `(set! (car '(symbol symbol2)) 3)` don't work, even though the second subform evaluates to a symbol-value.

To truly mutate data in-memory, one of the forms of `set-car!`, `set-cdr!`, `set-vector!` et cetera have to be used. These have completely different semantics and do evaluate their second sub-form, and what-ever data it evaluates to is then updated in-memory, changing all other symbol's value that share that memory with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about mutating vs rebinding. Both `set!` and `set-car!` change pointers. In your example, `l` initially points to the `cdr` of the pair, which is also a pair. When you `set! l`, you're telling it to point to the new location which holds `'(28 88)`.

Similarly, when you do `set-car!` you are saying that the `car` pointer will now point to a location B instead of its current location A, but the contents of A aren't mutated. For example:

```
(define list1 '(2 3)) 
(define list2 (list 72 list1 55))
(set-car! (cdr list2) 99)

list1 ==> '(2 3) 
list2 ==> '(72 99 55)
```